# Appmaker Thumbnail from Directory by Email

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a task lisk with Assignees. Right now I show email I get from field Assignee but I would like to show a profile picture instead. Id like to use the ThumbnailPhotoUrl from the directory but so far Ive failed to write a script that would return this value based on the Assignee.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have a script for this.

1. First make sure you have a directory data model in your App. Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory) if you don't have.
2. Once you have directory model in place, bind Image field with Data source as this Directory model. In the Image `url` provide `@datasource.item.ThumbnailPhotoUrl`.
3. This should solve your problem.

Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/document-approval/) template, here they have added logged in users' Photo in the Menu.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I do not need logged in users photo. The ticket is assigned to someone using directory and I want to show the Assignees picture.

Comment: Yes my answer aims for Assignees picture only, template part is just for your understanding. You have any queries in the answer provided?

Comment: Also please run the template provided in the answer. You will find a workflow in which you can add list of approvers. Now this is made using User Picker widget which works on Directory and has code for how to use Thumbnail photo as well